# Android empty process source code

Tags: android

While going through [Processes and Threads](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/processes-and-threads.html), I came across `Empty process`.  Where can I get source code for this process.

As we know `garbage collector` cannot guarantee removal of `static references\objects`. Does `Empty process` source code have any relation with `static` keyword.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Where can I get source code for this process.

Any process can become an empty process. Hence, the "source code for this process" is the same as the "source code for any process", and that code is partially in the Android framework and partially from app developers.

> Does Empty process source code have any relation with static keyword.

Not really.

Comment: Can you please elaborate more on what actually empty process contains. Only reference of apps or something else.

Comment: @Tauqir: It contains an app. "Empty" is a state of a process, just as "foreground", "visible", "service", and "background" are.

Comment: you said `partially from app developers`. How as an app developer I should understand that.

Comment: @Tauqir: I am sorry, but I do not understand your question. The documentation that you linked to is for writing Android apps. Android apps are built from source code written by app developers. Hence, processes that are associated with apps will contain code written by app developers.

Comment: Thanks for the elaboration and clearing my confusion as well.